# what is the reason for high % time in GC? for our app pool in APM perfmonitor tool, we see it crossing 99% and staying their for hours

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

Does this mean memory leakage? The %Time in GC goes to 99% even when noone is using the application. Could you please help me why this %time in GC counter is strangely behaving. this could be a code issue? application is in Asp.net and uses services to call some methods.
For disposing oracle connections, we used disposed method. we used standard dispose pattern in the application.
Could someone give me insights into this?

Comment: Could be a number of things, like creating a lot of variables and discarding them shortly after. Memory leaks refer more to variables created that AREN'T cleaned up by the GC, leading to out of memory crashes. What you want to do is use a memory analyzer tool of sorts, see which variables are piling up. It sounds to me like you just have inefficient code cause problems somewhere, for example doing complicated stuff on the main thread causing the program to wait until it is finished. This is not specific enough of a question though, so it's probably going to be closed. Good luck!

Comment: @G_V "variables" aren't allocations, and don't lead to GC; you might mean "objects", but objects that are "discarded shortly after" are actually pretty cheap to collect (GEN0 or GEN1 at worst), and don't usually cause GC problems *unless* you're allocating lots of objects in a tight loop; note that "doing complicated stuff on the main thread" *also* doesn't relate to GC in any way whatsoever, and: since "application is in Asp.net" (question body) there is no "main thread" to speak of

Comment: @MarcGravell cool, I figured there'd be freezing of the thread like in Android apps when the GC is busy cleaning. I did indeed mean objects. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @G_V blocking the UI thread in a client-side app (which this isn't) can indeed give huge performance problems, but it wouldn't relate to a "high % time in GC"

Comment: @MarcGravell - Maybe I'm misunderstanding what a "high % time in GC" actually is, can you clarify please? I interpreted it as "The garbage collector spends a lot of time clearing memory at the expense of performance", which is not the expected behavior.

Comment: @G_V yes, but what you described was simply: blocking the UI thread ("doing complicated stuff on the main thread causing the program to wait until it is finished"). When you block the UI thread, you prevent it from updating the UI - so an app appears frozen. That is a major performance issue, but is completely unrelated to GC.

Comment: @MarcGravell - It's actually the main reason why Android apps freeze and continue, by spending too much time garbage collecting on the main thread through the creation of objects and discarding them in rapid succession, for example in a `ListView`. I figured I'd comment since I expect the question to get removed for being so vague.

Comment: @G_V GC doesn't happen "on the main thread"; it happens everywhere at once, at least for a full collection. Now sure, suddenly allocating a ton of objects might *cause* a GC pause, but it doesn't matter what thread you do that on - you could allocate a ton of objects on a background thread, and you'd get the same problem. Sorry if I'm being pedantic, but there are two separate but related performance issues here, and it is IMO very important to keep a very clear sight on which we're talking about at all times. Sometimes it is both, but each manifests differently

Comment: @MarcGravell - I really appreciate you taking the time to explain. My GC knowledge mainly comes from Android and as I understand it, there the GC, which is independent of the execution threads, freezes execution threads from the outside to prevent them from running out of their limited allocated memory while it is clearing memory in that sandboxed space. That probably has more to do with the memory being allocated to a sandbox to prevent malicious apps from reading memory from other apps like how it used to be in older versions. Clarification is always good!

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to diagnose this kind of problem without very detailed analysis and direct observation of the measurements, but **on the surface** what this suggests is that you have a very large number of objects that have been allocated and which are retained for a long time - combined with some form of memory pressure. The net performance of full GC2 garbage collection is essentially bound by the number of *alive* / *reachable* objects in your system. So: what is the memory consumption? Is it in the GB area? If you have a large memory footprint, it doesn't *necessarily* mean a leak - but it *can* mean a leak. You can use memory analysis tools (usually against memory dump files) to investigate what objects exist, and how they are "rooted" - i.e. what is stopping them from being collected.

The *most common* things that cause this are:

- a huge object model loaded into memory and retained for a long period - for example, loading a large chunk of your database into very large arrays/lists and keeping them globally to "help performance"

  - a common case of the above is reusing a single "data context" / "unit of work" / etc in your DAL *between many requests*
- inappropriate use of events - especially registering objects to listen to  events on a long-lived object - that cause objects to stay reachable forever via a hypothetical event that actually never happens - for example, for every row doing `globalObj.SomeEvent += row.SomeHandler;` : once you've done this, `row` is reachable from `globalObj`, so if `globalObj` doesn't die: neither will `row`

  - a common case of the above is subscribing temporary objects to `static` events (and not unsubscribing them); `static` events don't die

As for what it is *in your case* - if there even is an actual problem: only deeper analysis will show what.