# Random LinQ-SQL errors and sudden database closing

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datacontext

There are 2 or 3 errors that are thrown sometimes in my ASP website. This usually happens when I go from a page to another very quickly. Usually, when I give it time, it does not

They are all related to the database connection and I try to figure out at what point or what triggers this behavior, specially when I cannot get the exact point/cause/scenario when this happens

So, my database context is handled like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace Models
{
    public partial class MainDataContext
    {
        [Function(Name = "NEWID", IsComposable = true)]
        public Guid Random()
        { // to prove not used by our C# code... 
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private static MainDataContext _DataContext;
        public static MainDataContext CurrentContext
        {
            get
            {
                Page page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;

                if (page != null)
                {
                    _DataContext = ((FrontEndPage)page).DataContext;
                }
                if (_DataContext == null)
                    _DataContext = new MainDataContext();

                return _DataContext;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will be used in `FrontEndPage`, which will have the `db` member to be used for communicating with the database,

```
using System;

using System.Web.UI;
using Models;
using Managers;

public class FrontEndPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected MainDataContext db = new MainDataContext();
    public OrderManager OrderManager = new OrderManager();

    public void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public MainDataContext DataContext
    {
        get
        {
            return db;
        }
    }

    public MasterPage MyMaster { get; set; }

    public Meta Meta { get; set; }

    public String CurrentPage { get; set; }
}
```

And from this one I derive any class for any page that I need, like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Models;

public partial class Page_Default : FrontEndPage
{
    protected Models.Content contactContent;

    protected ShopItem shopItem;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        contactContent = db.Contents.FirstOrDefault(a => a.FixedRef == "contact");
    }

    protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OrderManager.addItemToBasket(shopItem, "");
        db.SubmitChanges();
        Response.Redirect("/basket");
    }
}
```

Some of the errors that show up are:

`The operation cannot be performed during a call to SubmitChanges`

`There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.`

`ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is open.`

All this happens just as I navigate through pages. I press F5 and usually they disappear, the page shows up but then they come back at random, usually when I change from page to page fast. I guess this is related to the `MainDataContext` or the `FrontEndPage` classes, so I only added all the code for these two classes.

I will add more for the `Page_Default` one if needed but I wanna know if the way the database connection is created and kept is the problem for now.

Comment: Here's your first problem: **never**, ever, use singleton instances for database contexts. You should re-do every single piece of code that uses `public static MainDataContext CurrentContext` and remove `CurrentContext` and `_DataContext` completely

Comment: Wow. I just saw that it was a static member. I thought it was not all the time. Thanks. That could be a major cause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   private static MainDataContext _DataContext;
```

Boom; death. Never ever do this. Ever. Data contexts:

- are not thread-safe; it will scale to exactly one concurrent user
- need to be abandoned as changes happen and/or are aborted - so: you're now showing inconsistent and old data to your one concurrent user
- will cause large GC problems as it tracks all the objects, slowly loading your entire database into memory (twice, because of change tracking) and keeping it there; so you're now *very slowly* showing inconsistent and old data to your one concurrent user

A data-context should only live for the duration of a single request.

By coincidence, I called out this exact scenario (as a bad thing) just a few moments ago [to someone asking about bad performance due to garbage collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48559243/23354).

Comment: This is some very old code that I try to revamp. So old I almost forgot ASP so I am trying to bring it to the new standards. I guess I will have to investigate, see what is recommended nowadays to replace this

Comment: @bMain this has never ever been OK; this isn't a "new standards" thing - this code has always been fundamentally broken

Comment: I see. I will have a a look at best practices and change everything then. Won't even bother to find "the problem" as it seems everything is wrong behind the data context

Comment: @MarcGravell what would be the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: I assume https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/how-to-connect-to-a-database is not the best way either

Comment: But I have seen that `using (MainDataContext dataContext = new MainDataContext())` is praised in many places for performance and reliability

Comment: @bMain what the "right" lifetime of a data-context is depends a lot on your scenario; often "per request" is about right, so it *might be* that simply removing the `static` modifier fixes everything; having it per DB operation can add overhead  and means you never benefit from object re-use *in the same request*

Comment: According to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling, using the `using` statement and the pool is the best way to do it. i only have to see how much work I need to do to use this but if it's worth it I will do

Comment: @bMain I worry whenever I hear talk of "the best" way to do something; it is entirely contextual, and what works "best" for one scenario can be very different to what works "best" for another. For http requests, there is a very clear unit of work: the page life cycle; you *absolutely can* use data contexts per operation, but it may be faster, more efficient (by dodging some DB fetches by reusing loaded data) and more practical to use a per-request context. It *is* important to remember to add code to dispose the context as part of the end-page override, of course.